# JPA CrudRepository select by searching in list

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have an entity that contains multiple lists, with oneToMany associations:

```
@Entity
public class Data {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Tool> toolList= new ArrayList<Tool>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Level> levelList = new ArrayList<Level>();
}
```

I would like to write a @Query in the CrudRepository to select the Data entries that contains in List toolList a subset of tools (List subset). I am nut sure if this is possible or not.

Comment: do you want to create a custom repo ? and attach it to your crud repository ?

Comment: No, In my CrudRepository i want to add a method with custom Query. But from my toolList i want to check if an element from a subsetToolList is in toolLits then i return the Data.

Answer (score 0):

**Interface**

```
public interface Repository extends CrudRepository<Data, Integer //or your primary key>{

      @Query(value = "write the jpql query")
      eg - @Query(value = "select s.studentname from StudentEntity s where s.age > 20")
      List<String> query();

}
```

**In service**

```
@Transactional
public class Service {

    private final Repository repository;

    public Service(Repository repository){
        this.repository = repository;
    }


    public List<String> query(){
        return repository.query();      
    }

}
```

Now use the Service in your Controller using Autowired

Comment: I was not sure if the query is possible, this is my question.

Comment: I have used it please chexk this repo https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/Spring-Boot-DataJPA